# dotnet publish-iis looking for web.config in wrong place

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I'm having trouble getting `dotnet publish-iis` to run correctly.

To publish my project I'm using:

```
dotnet publish ./src/RetailGuardian.Web/ -o ./code_drop/RetailGuardian.Web --runtime dnet452
```

and I've set a postpublish script in my `project.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
}
```

The initial publish works properly, and places the code in a code_drop directory as expected (this was what I used to deploy in RC1 and it worked fine). However, publish-iis seems to not use the output path when attempting to locate the web.config. This is the output from when it runs:

```
Configuring the following project for use with IIS: './code_drop/RetailGuardian.Web'
No web.config found. Creating './code_drop/RetailGuardian.Web\web.config'
Could not find a part of the path 'G:\Projects\retailguardian\src\RetailGuardian.Web\code_drop\RetailGuardian.Web\web.config'.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'G:\Projects\retailguardian\src\RetailGuardian.Web\code_drop\RetailGuardian.Web\web.config'.
   at System.IO.Win32FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
   at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.PublishIISCommand.Run()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
publish: Published to ./code_drop/RetailGuardian.Web
Published 1/1 projects successfully
```

So it's trying to use `G:\Projects\retailguardian\src\RetailGuardian.Web\code_drop\RetailGuardian.Web\web.config` which is the source directory, rather than `G:\Projects\retailguardian\code_drop\RetailGuardian.Web\web.config` which is where the publish output is.

(Curiously it also reports that the publish was successful, even though the postpublish fails)

Comment: You published using a relative path: `-o ./code_drop/RetailGuardian.Web` since you publish from from the folder `G:\Projects\retailguardian\src\RetailGuardian.Web` the relative target path is resolved as `G:\Projects\retailguardian\src\RetailGuardian.Web\code_drop\RetailGuardian.Web`. I would expect the application to be published to this folder and therefore it should exist. Not sure why it isn't the case.

Comment: Yep this is exactly the reason that I'm confused

Comment: I see it now... It's a bug. I think the issue is that dotnet runs the tool in the folder where project.json is and you published from a different folder dotnet publish resolved your relative path relative to the folder you published from but publish-iis resolves the path relative to the folder where project.json is which are different folders and hence the mismatch. As a workaround you can publish using an absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug where a dotnet command resolves a relative path and then changes the current directory to invoke a tool which tries to resolve the path again but now it resolves it relative to a different folder so the final path is different. Thanks for reporting this - I opened an issue in the cli repo: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3528

Possible workarounds:

- use an absolute path as your output path when publishing
- publish from the project folder

Comment: Ok thanks that's great, will keep an eye on the issue then

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by adding web.config in include -> publishOptions from project.json:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
       ...
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My observation is, this happens when your terminal gets closed unexpectedly your server doesn't shut down properly. The simplest solution is start you application and stop it properly, and then try to execute the publish command.

execute the following sequence of commands :

```
dotnet start
ctrl + c
dotnet publish ..
```